# I don't know why CA should exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I think Fabric CA is needed when client node has to enroll for using Node.js Application. So if I use Fabric-cli when I invoke or queries chaincode, does Fabric CA need?

-> I thinking Fabric CA only useful for enrolling client node. And If client node does not exist in a network, Fabric CA can be replaced with Cryptogen Tool.

Comment: Can you clarify/repharse your question into concrete pointers? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thx. I modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do invokes and queries you need a user context. To get the user context you either need an user created by registering and enrolling an user via the CA server or you can use an already created user by the cryptogen tool.

So point is, once the user is created, you no longer need the CA Server or crytogen tool. 
In fact cryptogen tool is used to generate the certs of the entire network when the network is not created in the first place.

Also, when T-Certs will be supported in the future, for each transaction that you make, you would be required to get a T-Cert from the CA server to proceed with the transaction.

Comment: Thx so much! And If I don't use user context, is CA required?

Comment: userContext is not something you opt for while doing queries and invokes. It is mandatory to set the userContext while using any of the SDKs. The user's certificate would be used to sign the transactions. Also, as previously mentioned you do not need CA once you have your user enrolled.